# ElasticSearch: Get all elements where a parameter is not unique

Tags: elasticsearch

I know there is an aggregation to get the count of all unique value for a field.

For example

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "type_count" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "name"
            }
        }
    },
    "size":0
}
```

With this query I get the count of all the unique name.

But what I want is the list of all the names that are in the index more than once.

I want all the non unique names.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `terms` aggregation with a `min_doc_count` of 2, like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "type_count" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "name",
                "min_doc_count": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "size":0
}
```

Comment: It's working but my only issue is that when I need all the results and it's a big number and the aggregation doesn't support pagination. Is it possible to do the same thing with a query?

Comment: Can you define "big number" ?

Comment: It could be more than 100 000.

Comment: Note that you can achieve pseudo pagination using the [`partitions`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions) setting.